# Handling multiple <select> elements in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I am using a mixture of JavaScript and HTML in Blogger's HTML interface to create a dropdown feature that cycles through pictures. Bear with me; although I know how to code generally, I have no knowledge of JavaScript or HTML. This is my reduced code:

```html
<script language="javascript">
  function setImage(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="all_population" name="all_population" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aq1gUvq3RH4/X0buRMjyb4I/AAAAAAAAA1c/xaLW53hBW50oR5nncbAxMpAzhVbZGQO8wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EDsska671rY/X0budvqlQ-I/AAAAAAAAA1w/F-c6rmlpudk0SaOgMvi27biWIabYIW_5ACLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAsian.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="image-swap" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>

<script language="javascript">
  function setImage2(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="income_race" name="young_adult" onchange="setImage2(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tfwwZefpeiU/X0fSa5PcqwI/AAAAAAAAA2o/fE63pI0YCm4ooIu8PPN49_ilI6PbaV-IQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian_young.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FE6xtPVG_V8/X0fSldTMyeI/AAAAAAAAA2s/3UlvT5CvmyEDiUThPfs8wfJOdTdQmfvzgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAsian_young.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="young_adult" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>
```

From what I understand, I should create a second, different function `SetImage2()` for the second `<select>`. Otherwise, if my second `<select>`references `SetImage()`, the `<select>`will set the image below the first `<select>`(which was what was initially happening). However, when I do so, nothing is happening when I cycle through my second `<select>`. As far as I understand, I'm using the same logic as the first `<select>`, so I'm not sure why this second `<select>`isn't producing an image below it.

I would love if someone could provide some insight. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first function you have:

```
var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
```

This refers to *the first* element with the corresponding `name` attribute which is an `<img>`:

```
<img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="image-swap" src="" width="400" />
```

In `setImage2` you have:

```
var image = document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[0];
```

This refers to *the first* element with the corresponding `name` attribute which is a `<select>`:

```
<select id="income_race" name="young_adult" onchange="setImage2(this);">
```

You don't appear to need the name attribute on the select, so remove it. That way the image that follows it (that also has the same name attribute), which is now the second element with that name attribute, will become the first.

```html
<script language="javascript">
  function setImage(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="all_population" name="all_population" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aq1gUvq3RH4/X0buRMjyb4I/AAAAAAAAA1c/xaLW53hBW50oR5nncbAxMpAzhVbZGQO8wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EDsska671rY/X0budvqlQ-I/AAAAAAAAA1w/F-c6rmlpudk0SaOgMvi27biWIabYIW_5ACLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAsian.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="image-swap" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>

<script language="javascript">
  function setImage2(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="income_race" onchange="setImage2(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tfwwZefpeiU/X0fSa5PcqwI/AAAAAAAAA2o/fE63pI0YCm4ooIu8PPN49_ilI6PbaV-IQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian_young.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FE6xtPVG_V8/X0fSldTMyeI/AAAAAAAAA2s/3UlvT5CvmyEDiUThPfs8wfJOdTdQmfvzgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAsian_young.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="young_adult" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Comment: He will need to use `[2]` on his JavaScript. Perhaps he has a scenario to be using name, for form submission purposes so I wouldn't say he doesn't appear to need it. What if he actually wanted to submit the form and save the selected image, just as an example.

Comment: @MosiaThabo Why would he need `[2`]? That would mean that there are at least three elements with the `young_adult` name attribute and there are not

Comment: Lol! I actually meant `[1]`, what a mistake mate! lol! Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your attribute `name="young_adult"`. You are using `document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[0]` to access the elements. **But at index `[0]` is the `<select>` and not the `<img>` because `<img>` only  comes after `<select>` hence it doesn't work.**

For it to work you will need to change the following:

**Change the index to `[1]` on your javascript and it should work.**

```
var image = document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[1];
```

```html
<script language="javascript">
  function setImage(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="all_population" name="all_population" onchange="setImage(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aq1gUvq3RH4/X0buRMjyb4I/AAAAAAAAA1c/xaLW53hBW50oR5nncbAxMpAzhVbZGQO8wCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-EDsska671rY/X0budvqlQ-I/AAAAAAAAA1w/F-c6rmlpudk0SaOgMvi27biWIabYIW_5ACLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06_bar_chart_incomexAsian.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="image-swap" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>

<script language="javascript">
  function setImage2(select) {
    var image = document.getElementsByName("young_adult")[1];
    image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script><br />

<select id="income_race" name="young_adult" onchange="setImage2(this);">
  <option value="">Select One</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tfwwZefpeiU/X0fSa5PcqwI/AAAAAAAAA2o/fE63pI0YCm4ooIu8PPN49_ilI6PbaV-IQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAmerican%2BIndian_young.png;">American Indian</option>
  <option value="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FE6xtPVG_V8/X0fSldTMyeI/AAAAAAAAA2s/3UlvT5CvmyEDiUThPfs8wfJOdTdQmfvzgCLcBGAsYHQ/s1530/06.2_bar_chart_incomexAsian_young.png;">Asian</option>
</select><br />

<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
  <img data-original-height="1314" data-original-width="1530" height="344" name="young_adult" src="" width="400" />
</div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;"><br /></div>
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: left;"><br /></div>
```